# Value в < input> из javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде редактора страниц. Если в php это просто, то в javascript  не понимаю.  Нужен именно javascript, так как php не очень маневренный. Как при загрузке страницы, загрузить значение из javascript в value не нажимая никаких кнопок?

Answer (score 1):

Есть событие onload - тут подробнее [материал](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onload).

Можно его прописать body и передать функцию, которая будет выполняться после загрузки страницы.